# Subscription based notification implementation

Tags: php, android, mysql, push-notification

I have a database on a remote server for an android app. Let there are some categories `A,B,C` and each of the categories have some subcategories `A1,A2,A3`, `B1,B2`, `C1,C2,C3,C4`. Each subcategory has some child. Now if any user subscribe to `C1` then when a new entry under `C1` is added, the user will be notified. Similarly if any user subscribe to `A`, when a new entry is added in the remote database under `A` or `A1,A2,A3`, user will be notified.

How can this be implemented? It's 3rd day, I am out of idea.

**Added:**

How can I check from user-end that a new data is inserted in the server database of this user's subscribed category/subcategory. I think I have to write some query to do. But exactly what should be the database schema/query?

Comment: Are you asking about schema design, the insert stmt, the original query, the push technology? What is it all about? If it is entirely mysql related, then come chat for a bit in [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290)

Comment: I want the algorithm to do the task @Drew

Answer (score 0):

I think I would put a timestamp on each category and subcategory indicating when something was added to it.  The code to add items needs to then update that timestamp all the way up the tree when a new item is added.  The client makes a call to check the timestamp for all categories subscribed to and compares to the date and time when it last downloaded something to see if it needs to update.